What is the best way to know what is checked on a form and add a price on it like a POS? [Angular/TS]
What's the best way to do this other than many if statement if i'm going to compute stuff added to a cart or something
Form
acidBody: false
acidGlass: false
asphaltRemoval: false
ceilingDetail: false
ceramicBooster: false
ceramicCoating: false
clayBar: false
engineDetail: false
exteriorDetailing2: false
exteriorDetailing3: false
fullAcidCoating: false
fullDetail: false
glassCeramic: false
glassDetail: false
handWax: false
id: 1
interiorDetailing: false
machineWax: false
premiumWash: false
seatCleaning: true
size: "medium"
wax: false
wheelDetail: true

Here's the value of what I'll get if the form been submitted
Here's where I'll compare them so I can get the prices (these are the data that I will get from db)
    { 
      name : "small", 
      price : 150
     
    },
    { 
      name : "medium", 
      price : 180
     
    },
    { 
      name : "large", 
      price : 200
    },
    { 
      name : "xl", 
      price : 220
    },{ 
      name : "motor", 
      price : 100
    },{
      name: "wax",
      price: 300
    }
    //and so on

I don't want to do something like
if form.value.size == 'small' then price = 150 and confirm all of that
is there an easy way to do this?
how about the wax? if wax == true then price = 300 but there's no comparison so I ran out of ideas on how to do this
I tried looping but can't get a unique comparison to determine the price of each item
edit:
html:
  <form [formGroup]="carWashForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit1()" [validated]="customStylesValidated" cForm class="row g-3 needs-validation">
          <c-col xs="12" (change)="subTotal()">
            <c-form-check inline>
              <input cFormCheckInput checked id="size" formControlName="size" value="small" type="radio" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="small">Small</label>
            </c-form-check>
            <c-form-check inline>
              <input cFormCheckInput id="size" formControlName="size" value="medium" type="radio" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="medium">Medium</label>
            </c-form-check>
            <c-form-check inline>
              <input cFormCheckInput id="size" formControlName="size" value="large" type="radio" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="size">Large</label>
            </c-form-check>
            <c-form-check inline>
              <input cFormCheckInput id="size" formControlName="size" value="xl" type="radio" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="size">XL</label>
            </c-form-check>
            <c-form-check inline>
              <input cFormCheckInput checked id="motor" formControlName="size" value="motor" type="radio" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="motor">Motor</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="1">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="wax" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="wax" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="wax">Wax?</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="premiumWash" formControlName="premiumWash" type="checkbox" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="premiumWash">Premium Wash?</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="12">
            <p class="text-body-secondary big">
              <strong>Select Add-ons</strong>
            </p>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="handWax" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="handWax" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="handWax">Hand Wax</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="machineWax" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="machineWax" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="machineWax">Machine Wax</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="asphaltRemoval" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="asphaltRemoval" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="asphaltRemoval">Asphalt Removal</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="clayBar" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="clayBar" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="clayBar">Clay Bar</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="acidGlass" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="acidGlass" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="acidGlass">Acid Rain Removal - Glass</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="acidBody" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="acidBody" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="acidBody">Acid Rain Removal - Body</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="glassDetail" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="glassDetail" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="glassDetail">Glass Detail</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="glassCeramic" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="glassCeramic" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="glassCeramic">Glass Detail with Glass Coating</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="fullAcidCoating" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="fullAcidCoating" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="fullAcidCoating">Full Acid Rain Removal and Coating</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="ceilingDetail" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="ceilingDetail" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="ceilingDetail">Ceiling Detailing</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="seatCleaning" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="seatCleaning" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="seatCleaning">Seat Cleaning</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="interiorDetailing" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="interiorDetailing" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="interiorDetailing">Interior Detailing</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="exteriorDetailing2" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="exteriorDetailing2" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="exteriorDetailing2">Exterior Detailing 2 Step</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="exteriorDetailing3" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="exteriorDetailing3" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="exteriorDetailing3">Exterior Detailing 3 Step</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="fullDetail" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="fullDetail" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="fullDetail">Full Detail</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="engineDetail" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="engineDetail" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="engineDetail">Engine Detailing</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="wheelDetail" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="wheelDetail" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="wheelDetail">Wheel Detailing</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="ceramicCoating" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="ceramicCoating" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="ceramicCoating">Ceramic Coating</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="2">
            <c-form-check class="mb-3">
              <input cFormCheckInput id="ceramicBooster" (change)="subTotal()" type="checkbox" formControlName="ceramicBooster" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="ceramicBooster">Ceramic Booster</label>
            </c-form-check>
          </c-col>
          <!-- Total Price -->
          <c-col xs="12">
            <p class="text-body-secondary big">
              <strong>Total Price: {{totalPrice}}</strong>
            </p>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="12">
            <c-form-check>
              <input cFormCheckInput id="invalidCheck" name="invalidCheck" required type="checkbox" />
              <label cFormCheckLabel for="invalidCheck">Agree to terms and conditions</label>
            </c-form-check>
            <c-form-feedback [valid]="false">You must agree before submitting.</c-form-feedback>
          </c-col>
          <c-col xs="12">
            <button cButton class="me-1" color="primary" type="submit"> Submit form </button>
            <button (click)="onReset1()" cButton color="secondary" type="reset"> Reset </button>
          </c-col>
        </form>

component:
subTotal() {
    let info = this.carWashForm.value;
    Object.keys(info).forEach((key) => {
      const keyWithType = key as keyof typeof info;
      let value = info[keyWithType];
      if (typeof value === "string" && value === "") {
        info = { ...info, [keyWithType]: false };
      }

    });
    if(value === true){
}
  }


You could get all checked checkboxes with document.querySelectorAll("input:checked")

@mykaf We don't use queries like that from Angular applications.

@mykaf I would like to know how do I stick prices to them not if they are checked

"what is the best way to know what is checked on a form..."? @RuanMendes, good to know.

Asking about  "the best way" to do something is usually the sign of a poor question. There is no best way. You need to show your code and show what you have tired and what's not working, or what you would like to improve. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I imagine you can parametrizer your data.
Imagine you have several arrays
sizes= [{label:"Small",value:"small",price:150},
        {label:"Medium",value:"medium",price:180},
         ...
       ]
was=   [{label:"Was?",value:"was",price:80},
        {label:"PremiumWas?",value:"premiumWas",price:90}
       ]
addsOn=[{label:"Hand wax",value:"handWax",price:90},
        {label:"MachineWax",value:"machineWax",price:98},
        {label:"Asphal Removal",value:"asphaltRemoval",price:120},
        ...
       ]

Your form can be simply
  form = new FormGroup({
    size: new FormControl(''),
    was: new FormArray(this.was.map((x) => new FormControl(false))),
    addsOn: new FormArray(this.addsOn.map((x) => new FormControl(false))),
  });

You receive your data, so fill the form
  fillForm(data:any){
    const value:any={size:data.size,
                 was:[data.was,data.premiumWas],
                 addsOn:[]
                 }
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key=>{
        const index=this.addsOn.findIndex(a=>a.value==key);
        if (index>=0)
            value[index]=data[key]
    })
    this.form.patchValue(value)
  }

And when you have a form you can get the data
 getData(value:any)
 {
    const data:any={size:value.size,
                was:value?.was[0],
                premiumWas:value.was[1]
                }
    value.addsOn.forEach((x:boolean,i:number)=>{
        data[this.addsOn[i].value]=x
    })
    return data;    
 }
//you call as
   this.getData(this.form.value)

Now calculate the total is easer (futhermore you can use *ngFor to show the form.
 getPrice(value:any)
 {
    let price=(this.sizes.find(x=>x.value==this.form.value.size)||{price:0}).price
    price+=value.was[0]?this.was[0].price:0
    price+=value.was[1]?this.was[1].price:0
    value.addsOn.forEach((x:boolean,i:number)=>{
        if (x)
          price+=this.addsOn[i].price;
    })
    return price;
 }

//you call as
 getPrice(this.form.value)

see stackblitz
